# How does Python 3 enumerate choose the order of its items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

I have a folder with 1,199 CSV files. These files are all of the form 'BCx_mmyyPPO.csv' where `x.isin([6, 51, 55, 56, 57, 60, 200, 240, 269, 316, 340, 415])` and `mmyy` is 2-digit month followed by 2-digit year.

A snippet of the folder is below:

[folder sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dt4O.jpg)

I've written the following Python 3 code take all 1,199 files and jam them into one large CSV file:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

path = r'path/to/files'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
with open('PPO.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline()
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
```

The print step is functionally unnecessary but is the meat of what I'm trying to figure out. What logic does `enumerate()` use to choose the order of the items. I can't figure out how/why it chooses 'BC56_0608PPO.csv' as element 0? There really seems to be no rhyme or reason to it but it's problematic. I need the first file to be any of 'BCx_mm16PPO.csv' or 'BCx_mm17PPO.csv'.

My searches for anyone else with this problem are coming up short. I'm probably not looking correctly. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: It's nothing to do with `enumerate` -it's to do with the order `glob` returns matching files... Also - please don't post code as images - copy and paste it as a code block so others can read it in your question itself

Comment: please modify your question as requested by jon. When done you unlock the lock from the down-vote. If you do so that person can reconsider removing the downvote if the adjustments improved your question. Moved to editing, end of triage review. Welcome and enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: modified. Thank you for the pointers. And thank you also for clarifying that I was looking in the wrong place. That really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate does not change the order of an iterable, it just gives each item an index. The order of `glob.glob` is dependent on `os.listdir`, whose order is [arbitrary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).

You can sort it alphabetically by using `sorted`:

```
sorted(glob.glob(path + "/*.csv"))
```

... or use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to sort by size or last modification time:

```
sorted(glob.glob(path + "/*.csv"), key=os.path.getmtime)
sorted(glob.glob(path + "/*.csv"), key=os.path.getsize)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was focused on the wrong snippet of the code.